# Fixing cracked bathtub with hot glue

Tags: bathtub, adhesive, crack

I was cleaning my bathtub and noticed it's rusty around the drain hole, then I accidentally popped a hole through the bathtub. I am going to replace it next week, but is it possible to temporarily fix it with hot glue?

I know there are some shower repair kits or that I could use epoxy glue, but will hot glue be enough?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, hot glue is not enough. And I hope that by "replace" you refer to the whole bath.

If it's a super critical emergency sand away the rust around the hole, being careful not to punch another one, and use some kind of silicone based sealant.

Comment: Or putty epoxy.

Answer (score 0):

If you clean the area well, let your glue gun get nice and hot, and you lay a rubber or plastic patch over the top, I'd bet it would hold for a week. I've used hot glue extensively for repairs, some of which held back water. If done well it will work.